# When I export data to a csv from Python, the file is blank. When I use Print function to see the data, the first string is returned

Tags: python

I am very new to python. I am looking to import data from a .csv into python, use the fields as a variable so that I can string together the inbound data with machine language codes and then export the completed string to a .txt file.

I have the import.csv code working and have defined my variables into python and when I print the results I can see the first line as I need it to output to the .txt file. The issue that I am having is that in trying multiple different write statements, my file is either blank or I get errors.

```
import csv

with open('july 19.csv',mode='r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    for records in reader:
            EIN = records['EIN']
            DATE = records['Date Established']
            DUNS = records['DUNS #']
            COMPANYNAME = records['Company Name']
            lineout =('<S>'+ EIN+'$EIN '+EIN+'*'+DATE+')'+COMPANYNAME+'#D-U-N-S '+DUNS)
with open('test2.csv','w') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['EIN','Date Established','DUNS #','Company Name']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        writer.writerows({'EIN' : lineout})
```

```
  File "C:/Users/sstibal/PycharmProjects/Training/venv/Training.py", line 14, in <module>
    writer.writerows({'EIN' : lineout})
  File "C:\Users\sstibal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\csv.py", line 158, in writerows
    return self.writer.writerows(map(self._dict_to_list, rowdicts))
  File "C:\Users\sstibal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\csv.py", line 148, in _dict_to_list
    wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Comment: Please put the error into your post, and use a triple-backtick (```) to format your code instead of a quote (>).

Comment: `lineout` isn't defined in the scope of the second `with` statement and neither is `fieldnames`, either you haven't supplied all the code or this is likely your error

Comment: This is a great use for [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=read_csv#pandas.read_csv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the fieldnames parameter on `writer  = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames)`

The fieldnames parameter is a sequence of keys that identify the order in which values in the dictionary passed to the writerow() method are written to file f.

[docs](https://python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/library/csv.html)

Comment: Thank you for the information. I have updated the code and have exported the first line of data to the .csv file. When I change the writerow to writerows to export all of the data, I get an error. Not sure if I need to use a for loop statement to extract all of the rows of data or if I have my code setup incorrectly to export all rows.